# can i install another 1 GB ram when I have 2 GB ram?

Tags: memory

I have already installed 2GB of RAM, and I want to add some more. My OS is 32-bit Windows 7.

Would there be a problem in installing another Gig of RAM?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can. If you're concerned about the memory limit, the magic limit is about 4GB.

Comment: Hocus pocus, fiddle dee dee, unless you're using, PAE! But despite the magic, fi oh fum, it's just two, power thirty-two, minus one.

Comment: @neurolysis: that's so random but yet brilliant.

Comment: It was more a reference to "the magic limit" ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can install 1 GB RAM. 32 OS can access upto 4 GB ram. Before you install RAM make sure you have Ram slot available. Also make sure you buy exactly matching RAM Frequency/Speed to the one already installed.

Comment: Unless you're building a performance system (which with 2-3GB of RAM we can be pretty sure he's not), matching memory timings is usually pointless and unnecessary.

Comment: @music2myear: If you do not match the Mhz of 2 different RAM's then you are sure to have issues. Majority times you will observe core dumped by Windows or Linux. I have seen it many times on PC's that do not follow this basic rule.

Comment: If you do not match the timings, the system normally defaults to the slower of the two possible speeds. You do need the same type: DDR, DDR2, DDR3, etc. But in 10 years of consumer and business IT support, I have only found it necessary to match timings in cases where the system will be overclocked or when absolute speed is the absolute priority.